# how to solve null check operator in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a problem here, I'm trying to call the API and the response in the console shows the json response, but the screen shows an error like below,
Previously I managed to do it but when I tried to call it with a different API the result was not what I wanted.
Is there anyone here who can help me solve this problem.

[image]

> Here I attach the code
> the models I have

```
class KurikulumModel {
  String? status;
  String? code;
  List<Data>? data;

  KurikulumModel({status, code, data});

  KurikulumModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    status = json['status'];
    code = json['code'];
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      data = <Data>[];
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        data!.add(Data.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['status'] = status;
    data['code'] = code;
    if (data != null) {
      data['data'] = this.data!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Data {
  String? id;
  String? name;
  String? idSemester;
  String? smt;
  String? idProdi;
  String? prodi;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;
  String? createdBy;
  String? updatedBy;
  int? jumlahSksWajib;
  int? jumlahSksPilihan;
  int? jumlahSksSertifikat;
  int? status;
  int? stsHapus;

  Data(
      {id,
      name,
      idSemester,
      smt,
      idProdi,
      prodi,
      createdAt,
      updatedAt,
      createdBy,
      updatedBy,
      jumlahSksWajib,
      jumlahSksPilihan,
      jumlahSksSertifikat,
      status,
      stsHapus});

  Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    idSemester = json['id_semester'];
    smt = json['smt'];
    idProdi = json['id_prodi'];
    prodi = json['prodi'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
    createdBy = json['created_by'];
    updatedBy = json['updated_by'];
    jumlahSksWajib = json['jumlah_sks_wajib'];
    jumlahSksPilihan = json['jumlah_sks_pilihan'];
    jumlahSksSertifikat = json['jumlah_sks_sertifikat'];
    status = json['status'];
    stsHapus = json['sts_hapus'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['id'] = id;
    data['name'] = name;
    data['id_semester'] = idSemester;
    data['smt'] = smt;
    data['id_prodi'] = idProdi;
    data['prodi'] = prodi;
    data['created_at'] = createdAt;
    data['updated_at'] = updatedAt;
    data['created_by'] = createdBy;
    data['updated_by'] = updatedBy;
    data['jumlah_sks_wajib'] = jumlahSksWajib;
    data['jumlah_sks_pilihan'] = jumlahSksPilihan;
    data['jumlah_sks_sertifikat'] = jumlahSksSertifikat;
    data['status'] = status;
    data['sts_hapus'] = stsHapus;
    return data;
  }
}
```

> then i call

```
class KurikulumProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  Future<Data> getKurikulum() async {
    String url = Constant.baseURL;
    String token = await UtilSharedPreferences.getToken();
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(
        '$url/auth/mhs_siakad/kurikulum',
      ),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer $token',
      },
    );

    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.body);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return Data.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Token Expired!');
    }
  }
}
```

> and this is when i want to call it in API

```
...
FutureBuilder<Data>(
                          future: kurikulumProvider.getKurikulum(),
                          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                            return Table(
                              border: TableBorder.all(color: Colors.grey),
                              children: [
                                TableRow(children: [
                                  Column(children: [
                                    Text('Nama Kurikulum', style: bold6)
                                  ]),
                                  Column(children: [
                                    Text('Program Studi', style: bold6)
                                  ]),
                                  Column(children: [
                                    Text('Masa Berlaku', style: bold6)
                                  ]),
                                ]),
                                TableRow(
                                  children: [
                                    Column(children: [
                                      Text(snapshot.data!.name.toString(),
                                          style: regular6,
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.center)
                                    ]), ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the future is not completed yet but u already return the table modle.
you can listen to the snapshot is it already has data or not yet.

try changes your code like this

```
FutureBuilder<T>(
  future: future,
  builder: (
      BuildContext context,
      AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot,
      ) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
      //return something
    } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) {
        //return error
      } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
        //return your table
      } else {
        //return empty data
      }
    } else {
      //connection error return
    }
  },
),
```

i suggest to use any state management to handle this. provider/bloc to handle of the data.